# Windows 10 - see contents of thumbs.db

Tags: windows-10, thumbnails, thumbs.db

Is there a way to view the thumbnails cached by Windows 10 (`thumbcache_***.db` files)? I used to use a program `thumbs viewer` for that purpose - it worked fine on Windows Vista/7 but it seems to struggle with Windows 10 thumbnail databases.

Comment: See if this one works>>>https://thumbcacheviewer.github.io/

Comment: @Moab it does work perfectly! Feel free to post it as an answer

Comment: Software recommendations are not answers here at SU, that is why it is a comment, glad I could help.